# broken 3d viewport on different linux kernel

Tags: 3d-view

I'm running `blender 2.83.5` on **Ubuntu 20.04** with a newer kernel 5.7.13
and everything works fine except sometimes it crashes.
My problem is when I switch back to the supported 5.4 kernel my 3d viewport is broken.
in kernel 5.7.13:
[image: normal version in kernel 5.7.13]

in kernel 5.4:
[image: broken version in kernel 5.4]

I tried to render a image and everything seems to be the same.
what is going on here?

Comment: Display issues are almost always the gpu driver. Make sure that your driver is current.

Comment: I'm using nvidia-450 which is a tested proprietary driver. Linux drivers tend to not be the "latest" but that is as stable as it can get.